# How do I sum and display the result of each column of textboxes?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is an outline of what I want the program to do

[image: This is what I want the result to look like]
[image: The total results]

So this is my sum method. I used a nested array loop for making the textboxes. I also put the `displayTotal()` method.

```
 private void sumOfBonus()
    {
        bonusAttack = 0;
        bonusMain = 0;
        bonusSecondary = 0;

        attackPercent = 0;
        mainPercent = 0;
        secondaryPercent = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < statsBonus.GetLength(0); j++)
        {
            switch (statsBonus.GetLength(0))
            {
                case 0:
                    for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
                    {
                        bonusAttack += Convert.ToInt32(statsBonus[j, i]);
                    }

                    totalsBefore[j].Text = bonusAttack.ToString();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
                    {
                        bonusMain += Convert.ToInt32(statsBonus[j, i]);
                    }

                    totalsBefore[j].Text = bonusMain.ToString();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
                    {
                        bonusSecondary += Convert.ToInt32(statsBonus[j, i]);
                    }

                    totalsBefore[j].Text = bonusSecondary.ToString();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
                    {
                        attackPercent += Convert.ToInt32(statsBonus[j, i]);
                    }

                    totalsBefore[j].Text = attackPercent.ToString();
                    break;

                case 4:
                    for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
                    {
                        mainPercent += Convert.ToInt32(statsBonus[j, i]);
                    }

                    totalsBefore[j].Text = mainPercent.ToString();
                    break;

                case 5:
                    for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
                    {
                        secondaryPercent += Convert.ToInt32(statsBonus[j, i]);
                    }

                    totalsBefore[j].Text = secondaryPercent.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void totalsBoxes()
    {
    // this was called in the initializer method
        for (int i = 0; i < totalsBefore.Length; i++)
        {
            totalsBefore[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.totalsBefore[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190 + 60*i, 60);
            this.totalsBefore[i].Name = "totalBefore" + statsLabel[i];
            this.totalsBefore[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
            this.totalsBefore[i].TabIndex = i + 1;
            this.totalsBefore[i].ReadOnly = true;
            totalsLabel[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.totalsLabel[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190 + 60 * i, 36);
            this.totalsLabel[i].Name = "totalLabel" + i;
            this.totalsLabel[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 20);
            this.totalsLabel[i].AutoSize = true;
            this.totalsLabel[i].TabIndex = i + 1;
            this.totalsLabel[i].Text = statsLabel[i];
            totalsBefore[i].Parent = this;
            this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(totalsLabel[i]);
            this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(totalsBefore[i]);
        }
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sumofBonus();
}
```

However, when I click the button the results won't display or even write a zero. Also, how do I make the `sumOfBonus()` method more efficiently run?

Comment: more efficiently? you just said it doesn't work correctly! How could it be inefficient!

Comment: Can you provide code for the event handler of the button that is invoking this.

Comment: @MitchWheat I meant how do I make it efficient after it works? Are you allowed to ask how to make code efficient in this forum? Just wondering.

Comment: When is totalDisplay() called, i had the feeling you're using it at some point after doing all the sums and it basicly recreates your TextBoxes. Also how do you take the values from the controls to fill the statsBonus array , there might be a problem there. And last check your switch statement i think it should be just "j" in there if i follow your logic correctly

Comment: @PetkoPetkov Sorry for the confusion but the method totalDisplay(), now renamed to totalsBoxes(), is the method that generates the totalsBefore[] array. Where should the j variable be?

Comment: @puretppc your switch i think it should be switch(j) instead of switch(statsBonus.GetLength(0)). basicly GetLenght(0) would always return 6 or whatever is the size of the array. i'll try to write an answer with some pointers to consider.

Comment: @PetkoPetkov It helped but now I'm getting InvalidCastException error on line: bonusAttack += Convert.ToInt32(statsBonus[j, i]);

Comment: @puretppc put a break point at that line where you get the exception and look at the value of statsBonus[j,i] bear in mind Convert.ToIn32() may be culture dependant(using the wrong decimal separator for example).

Comment: @PetkoPetkov Oh now I get it. I forgot to say .Text beside it. No wonder it's not converting lol. Uh would it be possible if you know how to make this code more efficient?

Comment: @puretppc - Why are you worried about making it more efficient? Even if you process every textbox, that's only 18. Whatever code you write here is likely to be much faster than even redrawing the screen when the results change

Comment: @OrionEdwards I was thinking of shortening it since my program is going to be having a lot more features than this alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code and:
statsBonus declared as TextBox[] and totalsBefore declared as TextBox[]

You don't really need the switch statement at all

```
for (int j = 0; j < statsBonus.GetLength(0); j++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        sum+= Int32.Parse(statsBonus[j,i].Text);
    }
    totalsBefore[j].Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

It's basically your own code with removed switch block.